# Pic18F2520 Reset

Tags: microcontroller, pic, xc8

I am trying to control a BMP180 through I2C protocol. The problem is that the Pic resets all the time. I changed the Pic and it is the same.

The config code is the next:

```
#include <xc.h>

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config OSC = INTIO7     // Oscillator Selection bits (Internal     oscillator block, CLKO function on RA6, port function on RA7)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = SBORDIS  // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out  Reset enabled in hardware only (SBOREN is disabled))
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown Out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF         // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = PORTC   // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config PBADEN = ON      // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as analog input channels on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP enabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
```

and the main code:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define EAUSART_V4  

#include <plib/usart.h> 
#include "i2c.h"

#define OSCCON_Init         0b11111111   

#define BMP180_W 0xEE
#define BMP180_R 0xEF
#define I2C_master_ACK 1
#define I2C_master_NOACK 0
#define I2C_WRITE_CMD 0
#define I2C_READ_CMD 1
#define I2C_START_CMD 0
#define I2C_REP_START_CMD 1
#define I2C_REQ_ACK 0
#define I2C_REQ_NOACK 0

#define SDA_TRIS  TRISCbits.RC4
#define SCL_TRIS  TRISCbits.RC3


char CaracterRx;
int nummer = 0;


uint8_t data;
uint16_t temperature;

uint8_t BMP180_present(void);
void i2c_master_ack(unsigned char);
uint16_t BMP180_Temperature_Lecture(void);

void main(void) {

char hello[] ={"hello there\r\n\0"};

 SSPSTATbits.CKE = 1;

SDA_TRIS = 1;
SCL_TRIS = 1;

OSCCON = OSCCON_Init;

OpenUSART(USART_TX_INT_ON &
        USART_RX_INT_ON &       
        USART_ASYNCH_MODE &     
        USART_EIGHT_BIT &       
        USART_CONT_RX &         
        USART_BRGH_HIGH, 51);  



 putsUSART("2"); 
 for(int i=0; i<10 ; i++)
__delay_ms(50);

SSPADD=19; 
OpenI2C(MASTER,SLEW_OFF);


putsUSART(&hello); 
for(int i=0; i<10 ; i++)
  __delay_ms(50);

while(1)
{
data = BMP180_present();

temperature = BMP180_Temperature_Lecture();
nummer = data;
putsUSART(nummer);

for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
   __delay_ms(50);

}
}



uint8_t BMP180_present(void)
{//returns true if a bmp is detected.
//Detection achieved by looking at the device ID, which is fixed at 0x55. 
uint8_t Id;
StartI2C();
WriteI2C(BMP180_W);
WriteI2C(0xD0);
RestartI2C();
WriteI2C(BMP180_R);
Id=ReadI2C();
StopI2C();

return Id;
}

uint16_t BMP180_Temperature_Lecture(void)
{
uint16_t value;
uint8_t prueba1, prueba2;
StartI2C();
WriteI2C(BMP180_W);
WriteI2C(0xF4);
WriteI2C(0x2E);
StopI2C();
__delay_ms(5);

WriteI2C(BMP180_W);
WriteI2C(0xF6);
RestartI2C();
WriteI2C(BMP180_R);
prueba1=ReadI2C();//Value in F6
i2c_master_ack(I2C_master_ACK);
prueba2=ReadI2C();//Value in F7
i2c_master_ack(I2C_master_NOACK);
StopI2C();

value = prueba1<<8 | prueba2;

return value;

}

void i2c_master_ack(unsigned char ack_type)
{
SSPCON2bits.ACKDT = ack_type; // 1 = Not Acknowledge, 0 = Acknowledge
SSPCON2bits.ACKEN = 1; // Enable Acknowledge
while (SSPCON2bits.ACKEN == 1);
}
```

I send the data via Serial to an Arduino and this prints it on the computer. Almost always when I try to print it, it prints only "2", and sometimes, he writes the sentence and prints the data from the module which contains the BMP180. But most of the time, what Arduino shows me is: 22222222...
I have tested setting the MCLR = OFF, but it is still the same.

The lanes SDA and SCL have a resistance of 4.7k to 3.5V. The module is powered with 3.5V, but the pic with 5V.
I do not think that the problem is too high intensity with this module.
Am I maybe forgetting something?

It is curious that when I touch the pic (when I try to change some wire or something) it automatically resets.

Thank you very much.

Manuel.

Comment: I hope you have provided a bias on unconnected input pins to stop them floating. The Reset line too?

Comment: Have you connected all grounds? The module ground, the PIC ground and the Arduino ground.

Comment: Actually, I didn't connect anything to the other pins. The reset line is on 5V all time. Yes, all grounds are connected.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have some serious noise issues there. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code at first glance. When an unused pin is left floating, it acts like a high-impedance antenna and basically picks up on any and all signals in the vicinity, whatever they may be. Power consumption also rises dramatically in this case. This may explain why the PIC resets every time you touch it. Based on personal experience, I suggest you do some or all of the following:

1. Set all your unused pins as digital outputs and pull them down to gnd using the LAT register. For example, if you're not using your RA2 pin, put this at the beginning of your main function:

   TRISAbits.RA2 = 0;

   LATAbits.LATA2 = 0;

Do this for all your unused pins. It will decrease your power consumption dramatically.

2. Make sure you've connected the right resistance value between the 5V(in your case) and the reset pin. There are issues sometimes if the value is higher or lower than recommended in the datasheet.
3. Measure the PIC power supply voltage on the corresponding pins. You could do this with a multimeter, but I recommend that you use an oscilloscope if you have access to one. Hook it up to the power supply pins of the PIC and measure the value while you're sending data over the I2C. There could be a drop in the supply voltage, which causes a brown-out reset, i.e. the voltage drops below 3V in your case and the controller resets. If that's the case, clearing the BOREN bit would be a possible solution, however, such power drops indicate a bigger problem with your circuit, so I suggest you look into it some more.